# How to convert this combination into simple series and parallel?

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistance

[image]

In this problem we are not using delta wye method. But I don’t know how they converted this combination into simple series and parallel combination. Help :(

Comment: It's the exact same circuit just drawn differently, have a look at what nodes are actually connected to eachother. For example with the 3 Ohm resistor it's nodes are connected to the voltage source so it must be in parallel with it, While also touching one node of all the other resistors

Comment: Clear your mind and then get out a piece of paper ("A".) Start by looking at the circular schematic ("B".) Pick any part at all and draw that same part on the clean "A". Put an X through the part you just selected in "B". Now, pick the next part from "B" to move, knowing that it must be directly connected to the part you just put an X through. Now draw this 2nd part on "A" and attach it to the 1st part on "A". Continue the process of moving parts and making sure that the same connections are all retained. Do this in different ways a few times. Eventually, it becomes a lot easier.

Answer (score 3):

Look more closely at the original schematic and count the actual nodes.
If it helps, highlight them in different colours.

[image]

Note there are actually only three nodes, unique voltage points, in the circuit.

As such you can redraw the circuit starting with the battery.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHRMea.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As you can see, both R1 and R2 begin and end at the same nodes so are in parallel.

R4 is simply in parallel with the battery.

**TIP:** Whenever you are given assignments like this be on the lookout for things that let you redraw the circuit. The assignments are intentionally made obscure to make you think.

Answer (score 0):

Apply nodal analysis,

- 2 Ohm and 6 Ohm are connected to same nodes, so they are in parallel
- Next, 1.5 Ohm is in series with the parallel combination
  The figure is a just simplified form of previous one.